# Creating a module subclass in a Python extension

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Python extension module with multi-phase initialization, following the advice I got from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464426/dynamic-attribute-in-a-python-c-module). [PEP 489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0489/#the-py-mod-create-slot) suggests that it is preferable for the `Py_mod_create` function to return a module subclass, which presumably means a subclass of `PyModule`, but I cannot figure out how to do this. In all my attempts, the module segfaults when it is imported. It works fine if `Py_mod_create` returns some other object, (one which is not a subclass of `PyModule`), but I am not sure if this will cause problems in future, since `isinstance(mymodule, types.ModuleType)` returns false in this case.

Following [the docs on subclassing built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/newtypes.html#subclassing-other-types), I set `tp_base` to `PyModule_Type`, and my `tp_init` function calls `PyModule_Type.tp_init`. The docs also suggest that my structure should contain the superclass structure at the beginning, which in this case is `PyModuleObject`. This structure is not in the public Python header files, (it is defined in `moduleobject.c` in the Python sources), so for now I copied and paste the definitions of the `PyModuleObject` fields at the start of my structure. The complete code looks like this:

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct testmod_s {
  // Fields copied from PyModuleObject in moduleobject.c
  PyObject_HEAD
  PyObject *md_dict;
  struct PyModuleDef *md_def;
  void *md_state;
  PyObject *md_weaklist;
  PyObject *md_name;
};

static int testmod_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds);
static PyObject *testmod_create(PyObject *spec, PyModuleDef *def);

static PyModuleDef_Slot testmod_slots[] = {
  {Py_mod_create, testmod_create},
  {0, 0}  /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef testmod_def = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,    /* m_base */
  "testmod",                /* m_name */
  NULL,                     /* m_doc */
  sizeof(struct testmod_s), /* m_size */
  NULL,                     /* m_methods */
  testmod_slots,            /* m_slots */
  NULL,                     /* m_traverse */
  NULL,                     /* m_clear */
  NULL                      /* m_free */
};

static PyTypeObject testmodtype = {
  PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT (NULL, 0)
  "testmodtype",                /* tp_name */
  sizeof (struct testmod_s),    /* tp_basicsize */
  /* fields omitted for brevity, all set to zero */
  Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT |
  Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,          /* tp_flags */
  /* fields omitted for brevity, all set to zero */
  testmod_init,                 /* tp_init */
  0,                            /* tp_alloc */
  0,                            /* tp_new */
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_testmod(void)
{
  testmodtype.tp_base = &PyModule_Type;
  if (PyType_Ready(&testmodtype)) {
    return NULL;
  }
  PyObject *moduledef = PyModuleDef_Init(&testmod_def);
  if (moduledef == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return moduledef;
}

static int testmod_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
  if (PyModule_Type.tp_init((PyObject *)self, args, kwds) < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

static PyObject *testmod_create(PyObject *spec, PyModuleDef *def)
{
  struct testmod_s *module = PyObject_New(struct testmod_s, &testmodtype);
  if (module == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return (PyObject *) module;
}
```

Importing this module causes a segfault. What am I doing wrong?

I am running Python 3.8.5 on macOS 12.0.1 with a build from Anaconda:

```py
>>> sys.version
'3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) \n[Clang 10.0.0 ]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests I could build a custom module type by copying parts of code from moduleobject.c

Your problem is that your code does create an instance of a subclass of module, but never initializes it and gets random values in key members. Additionaly, modules are expected to be gc collectables, so you have to create your custom module with `PyObject_GC_New`.

The following code replaces your initial `testmod_create` function with a full initialization of the module:

```
...
// copied from moduleobject.c
static int
module_init_dict(struct testmod_s* mod, PyObject* md_dict,
    PyObject* name, PyObject* doc)
{
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__name__);
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__doc__);
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__package__);
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__loader__);
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__spec__);

    if (md_dict == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (doc == NULL)
        doc = Py_None;

    if (_PyDict_SetItemId(md_dict, &PyId___name__, name) != 0)
        return -1;
    if (_PyDict_SetItemId(md_dict, &PyId___doc__, doc) != 0)
        return -1;
    if (_PyDict_SetItemId(md_dict, &PyId___package__, Py_None) != 0)
        return -1;
    if (_PyDict_SetItemId(md_dict, &PyId___loader__, Py_None) != 0)
        return -1;
    if (_PyDict_SetItemId(md_dict, &PyId___spec__, Py_None) != 0)
        return -1;
    if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(name)) {
        Py_INCREF(name);
        Py_XSETREF(mod->md_name, name);
    }

    return 0;
}

static PyObject* testmod_create(PyObject* spec, PyModuleDef* def)
{
    struct testmod_s* module = PyObject_GC_New(struct testmod_s, &testmodtype);
    if (module == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    PyObject* name = PyUnicode_FromString("testmod");
    if (name == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(module);
        return 0;
    }
    module->md_def = NULL;
    module->md_state = NULL;
    module->md_weaklist = NULL;
    module->md_name = NULL;
    module->md_dict = PyDict_New();
    int cr = module_init_dict(module, module->md_dict, name, NULL);
    Py_DECREF(name);
    if (cr != 0) {
        Py_DECREF(module);
        return NULL;
    }

    return (PyObject*)module;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It find it hard to believe that this is what is intended by the term "module subclass" in PEP 489. I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: Well in my tests, I haved added an integer member to the module, a getter/setter for the `x` variable and could indeed use it as a *module property*: `import testmod` `print(testmod.x)` actually invoked the getter and `testmod.x = 5` invoked the setter.